# How to handle multi touch with getRawX()/getRawY() pointer Android

Tags: android, pointers, touch, scale, multi-touch

I followed this great sample to handle the multi touch :
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html  :

```
        pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            lastX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
            lastY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
```

Here pointer ids are handled with getX() and getY() which is working great.

But in my use case I have to scale the view inside the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` with setScaleX(). The problem I'm facing is exactly the same that the one here :
[Why motionEvent.getX() return inconsistent values, when using setScaleX()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786541/why-motionevent-getx-return-inconsistent-values-when-using-setscalex)

My retrieved values are jumping with `setScaleX()` because of the coordinates.
Then I tried to achieve it with `event.getRawX()` which solved the jumping issue during the scale.

I'm now asking how to reproduce the same logic used for `getX()` to handle the multi touch with `getRawX()` ? Or any workaround

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: @RafaelLima no answer sorry